# how to detect if a select option exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to detect if a select option exists, (preferably in jquery), for example:

```js
let str = 'lorem';
//if(str exists inside `sel options`){console.log('exists');}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='sel'>
<option>lorem</option>
<option>ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You just want to see if it exist as an available option in the dropdown through code?

Comment: You can use `.filter()` function to get elements with the required text. then you  can use it in if condition along with .length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help?

```js
let str = 'lorem';

$("#sel option").each(function() {

  var option = $(this).text();

  if (option === str) {
    console.log("Exists");

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='sel'>
  <option>lorem</option>
  <option>ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tested this using `ipsum` in `str` as well

Answer (score 1):

Query the `#sel options` id + tag and get all selectors that fit that element selector. Iterate over the elements using `for` with .length on the element list. Then conditional to check if the target is present using the key.

```js
let str = 'lorem';
let options = document.querySelectorAll('#sel option');
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  if (options[i].textContent === str) {
    console.log(options[i].textContent + " - Exists")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='sel'>
  <option>lorem</option>
  <option>ipsum</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```js
let str = 'lorem';
let $options = $('#sel option');
$options.each(function(){
  if($(this).text() === str ){
    console.log(str + ' - Exists')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='sel'>
  <option>lorem</option>
  <option>ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$('#sel').find('option[text="lorem"]');`

Comment: `let x = $('#sel').find('option[text="lorem"]').length;` - doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. option has no value

   $('#sel option').filter(function(){return $(this).html()=="ipsum";}).length > 0
2. option has value

   $('#sel option[value="ipsum"]').length > 0

Comment: why not `$('#sel option').text()` - if wo value

Comment: $('#sel option').text() doesn't work, we have to filter the option object at first, by filter function or selector. $('#sel option:contains("lorem")') may work but it's "contains" and NOT exact equals